# Gunicorn: site slows down after inactivity period

Tags: django, web-deployment, gunicorn, webfaction

I'm hosting a Django site in Webfaction with gunicorn (a master + 4 workers). I've settled with 4 because I've had good results in the past for the traffic I get, and "CPU cores * 2 + 1" just eats up my RAM.

Under normal usage, the gunicorn workers take around 45 Mb or RAM each, and I'm getting page load times of just under a second. Now, after sitting unattended for a few hours, the workers will go down to anything from 5 to 15 Mb of RAM each. If I visit the site at that point, it takes more than 10 seconds to get a response from the server. After browsing 2 or 3 pages, the workers go back to the normal memory usage and the site becomes speedy again.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10403335/1330003) (see point 1), gunicorn should have the site ready to go at any time, without needing a "warm up" period after not receiving requests for a while. This is consistent with what I've seen when using this setup in at least a dozen other sites: gunicorn is simply there, ready to go at any time.

Is it normal for the workers to lower their memory consumption to such low levels? How can I get rid of the long response times after inactivity?

Comment: What cloud service provider are you using?