# What does the SWAP column in top command stand for?

Tags: linux, swap, top-command

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to find out which processes are swapping in linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479953/how-to-find-out-which-processes-are-swapping-in-linux)

I gave the top command and sorted the output using the sort below  field.

P: SWAP       = Swapped size (kb)

I was looking for the process id which was consuming the maximum amount of swap.

Here is the output I got

SWAP    COMMAND

1.1g    java
979m    java
568m    java

What does this mean? It does not seem to be the swap space used by these processes because at the start of the top command output the Swap detail is given as

Swap:  2096440k total,   830636k used,

The total amount of swap is 1.99g so the first three processes cannot consume so much. So what does this column exactly stand for?

Additionally, is there a way to hunt down a process which is consuming high swap space?

Comment: Did you read the man page? `Memory that is not resident but is present in a task.  This is memory that has been swapped out  but  could include additional non-resident memory.  This column is calculated by subtracting physical memory from virtual memory.` So it has nothing to do with the swap partition IMHO.

Comment: Thanks Huygens. So is there any way to find out what is consuming swap space? May not be exact but at least an approximation?

Comment: you should check the answers from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/479953/482811?stw=1