# Know how much swap is used by each process on Linux

Tags: linux, bash

I use the following script (from this blog http://northernmost.org/blog/find-out-what-is-using-your-swap) to know for each process how much swap it is using

```
#!/bin/bash
# Get current swap usage for all running processes
# Erik Ljungstrom 27/05/2011
SUM=0
OVERALL=0
for DIR in `find /proc/ -maxdepth 1 -type d | egrep "^/proc/[0-9]"` ; do
PID=`echo $DIR | cut -d / -f 3`
PROGNAME=`ps -p $PID -o comm --no-headers`
for SWAP in `grep Swap $DIR/smaps 2>/dev/null| awk '{ print $2 }'`
do
let SUM=$SUM+$SWAP
done
echo "PID=$PID - Swap used: $SUM - ($PROGNAME )"
let OVERALL=$OVERALL+$SUM
SUM=0

done
echo "Overall swap used: $OVERALL"
```

The overall swap used output by this script does not match the swap used output by the ***free*** command.

Is anybody able to explain why ?

Comment: The kernel can use some swap space for housekeeping.  I suspect this is what you're seeing.  IIRC, `mmap`'d files use swap in some situations.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to find out which processes are swapping in linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/479953/how-to-find-out-which-processes-are-swapping-in-linux)

Answer (score 2):

Swap usage by each process could be found out by using the command "top" then pressing "O" then selecting  "P: SWAP       = Swapped size (kb)" from the given options. The processes will be sorted out based on the swap usage.

Latest version of top v3.3.3 does not have the "O" option.