# Linux: How do I get the swap used by a process?

Tags: linux, memory

Getting the Resident Set Size is straightforward (`getrusage()` or `/proc/self/statm`), but how do I get the amount of swap? From `man 5 proc` about /proc/self/stat:

```
nswap %lu   Number of pages swapped (not maintained).

cnswap %lu  Cumulative nswap for child processes (not maintained).
```

Any other thoughts?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to find out which processes are swapping in linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/479953/how-to-find-out-which-processes-are-swapping-in-linux)

Comment: @hek2mgl This is not duplicate at all.  The other question is asking about how to get a list of processes that use swap.  This question is about how, as a developer, you can check swap usage by your program from inside the code.

Comment: @AleksG Read the answers. It took me 2 seconds to google this

Comment: @hek2mgl I have.  None of them is related to this question.

Comment: `It is not possible to get the exact size of used swap space of a process. Top fakes this information by making SWAP = VIRT - RES, but that is not a good ....` is not related to this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if you have `VmSwap` in `/proc/$PROCESS/status`. For example: `grep VmSwap /proc/1/status`